# Excel coding enter value chronologically

Tags: python, excel, reference

I'm trying to automate a spreadsheet to enter a value referencing another workbook but populate the next consecutive cell with the value from the same reference the following day but I don't want the previous cell value to change.

I imagine I could tell Cell A1 to reference and input then terminate and A2 to do the same the following day when I open the workbook and excel sees the date has changed?

Simply Im tracking daily values from another workbook and need it to record similar to:

```
             Value        DIFFERENCE
MONDAY         100
TUESDAY        150             50
WEDNESDAY      300            150
```

If I tell the cell to reference the other workbook at the moment, I know it will overwrite Monday as soon as Tuesday comes, which I don't want...

I've tried simply using A2(Monday)

```
=REF(exampleworkbook,examplecell)
```

etc to get the right value but how do i get that to freeze so that A3(Tuesday) references the same cell but doesn't alter A2?

Comment: Use VBA likely.

Comment: As BigBen states VBA might normally be used to do this if its a case you want to open the workbook and have it update with the new day's data. The Xlwings add-in could be used if you wanted the same, open the workbook and have it update, but use Python to execute changes rather than VBA. Otherwise you write a Python script that runs first, updates the workbook/sheet then when you open it you see the updated data.